# Как получить group- и/или childPosition выбранного элемента списка?

Tags: expandablelistview, android, java, adapter

**Дано**: ExpandableListView со своим адаптером, наследующим BaseExpandableListAdapter. Списку приданы слушатели groupClickListener и childClickListener. В обоих по клику по элементу делаю так:

```
mDrawerList.setSelectedChild(groupPosition, childPosition, true);
```

В итоге список отображает выбранный элемент (группу или ребёнка), подсвечивая его с помощью "@< selector/>".

Сам список используется как выползающее меню в NavigationDrawer.

**Проблема**: выделение отображается только после того, как список будет прокручен. Т.е. сначала кликаю по элементу списка - ничего не происходит внешне, но програмно элемент отмечен (выбран). Далее дёргаю список и элемент окрашивается цветом, указанным в селекторе.

**Пробовал**:

```
expListView.notifyDataSetChanged(); //не помогает.
```

**Возможное решение**: Я абсолютно уверен, что проблему можно решить меняя цвет элемента в методах адаптера, их отрисовывающего:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
ViewGroup parent)
{
//получаем groupPosition и childPosition выбранного элемента
//тут меняем цвет выбранного элемента, сравнивая groupPosition и childPosition выбранного элемента с текущим
}
```

Точно уверен, т.к. этот метод вызывается каждый раз, когда список выезжает из-за края экрана.

Весь вопрос в том, как получить **groupPosition** и **childPosition** выбранного элемента.

Часами рылся в доках и методах адаптера и списка, но так ничего и не понял. Методы, которые должны возвращать данные по выбранному элементу, всё время возвращают одинаковые значения, кои непонятно куда пихать.

Я уже готов сдаться и писать **groupPosition** и **childPosition** в переменные активити при клике по элементу и в адаптере их оттуда забирать. Но активити у меня много с одним и тем же списком - много лишнего кода и переменных.

**Вопрос**: как таки получить **groupPosition** и **childPosition** выбранного (selected) элемента из списка/адаптера?

**Обновление 0**

При клике всё верно выводит через этот код:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
{
    //test
    final long groupChildFlatPosition=ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    final int groupPos1 = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(groupChildFlatPosition);//(groupChildFlatPosition);
    final int childPos1 = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(groupChildFlatPosition);
    System.out.println("onChildClick_groupPos1: " + groupPos1 + "/ childPos1: "+childPos1);
}

@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)
{
    //test
    final long packedPosition = parent.getExpandableListPosition(groupPosition);
    final int groupPosition1 = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);
    System.out.println("onGroupClick_groupPosition1: "+groupPosition1);
}
```

В адаптере же, вот этот код (в getChildView() ):

```
final long groupChildPositionSelected=((ExpandableListView)parent).getSelectedPosition();
                switch(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(groupChildPositionSelected)) {
                    case ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD:
                        System.out.println("position type: child");
                        break;

                    case ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP:
                        System.out.println("position type: group");
                        break;

                    case ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_NULL:
                        System.out.println("position type: null");
                        break;
                }
                final int groupPos1 = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(groupChildPositionSelected);//(groupChildFlatPosition);
                final int childPos1 = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(groupChildPositionSelected);
                System.out.println("FROM_ADAPTER_groupPos1: " + groupPos1 + "/ childPos1: "+childPos1);
```

Выводит:

> position type: null
>
> FROM_ADAPTER_groupPos1: -1/ childPos1: -1

Т.е. в адаптере не получается получить какие-либо данные о выбранном элементе из списка.

Comment: Вот это смотрели?    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659207/expandablelistview-getpackedpositiongroup-always-returns-0-in-onitemlongclick

Comment: @Andreich, смотрел, попробовал ещё раз. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да это уже неактуальная проблема. :)

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно вам поможет вот этот хак -

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014315/5292979

двумерный массив для сохранения состояния child и group item-ов

```
  private selectedStatus[][];
```

в конструкторе инициализируете дефолтное состояние

```
  public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, int groupCount, int childCount) {
     selectedStatus = new boolean[groupCount][];
     for (int i = 0; i < groupCount); i++) {
        selectedStatus[i] = new boolean[childCheckCursor.getCount()];
        for (int j = 0; j < childCount; j++) {
            selectedStatus[i][j] = false;
        }
     }
  }
```

на основании статуса выставляете фон

```
@Override 
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    final View v = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent); 
    if(selectedStatus[groupPosition][childPosition]){
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);                          
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
    }
    return v; 
}
```

добавляете метод позволяющий изменить предыдущее состояние и установить новое в адаптер

```
setSelectedStatus (int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
   for (int i = 0; i < selectedStatus.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < checkedStatus[i].length; j++) {
          if(i == groupPosition && j == childPosition) {
             selectedStatus[i][j] = true;
          } else {
             selectedStatus[i][j] = false;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

в листенере пользуетесь

```
lv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        YuorListAdapter adapter = (YuorListAdapter) parent.getAdapter; // само собой это ваш адаптер
        adapter.setSelectedStatus(groupPosition, childPosition);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй вот так

```
mDrawerList.setSelectedChild(groupPosition, childPosition, true);
mDrawerList.expandGroup(0);
```